# Change the time and date format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I want to remove the seconds and the result i want as like this
14 july 14 10:44.

```
2014-07-14 10:44:35
```

I done with this code as

```
CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( `login_timestamp` , '%M %e, %Y' ) , ' ', TIME_FORMAT(`login_timestamp` , '%T' ) )
```

Is there any other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(login_timestamp,'%d %M %y %H:%i') FROM table_name;
```

[**Reference**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Date() will only produce the date

```
date('$time')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2014-07-14 10:44:35', '%d %M %y %l:%i');
```